# to know the device as iphone or ipad or ipod + phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am making an app in IOS with cordova. In cordova index.html, can i know if the device is a iphone, ipad, ipod like we use navigator.userAgent to know if the browser is a android or IOS.

I am having an ipod, and both the following conditions are coming true for it.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/))
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipod/))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to check for

```
navigator.platform
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an iPod also says its an iPhone could you check for the iPod user agent first like this:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipod/)) //I'm an iPod
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipad/)) //I'm an iPad
else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/)) //I'm an iPhone
```

Does that work?